# CSS: Align div on bottom

Tags: css

I try to align a div at the bottom of a parent div. I tried the following:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuf0m41z/)

I thought it would work with:

```
.bottom-menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But as you can see in the fiddle it does not work. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give a `width` to it as well. also you should use `position: relative` on the parent (the default is `static`). See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wuf0m41z/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could also specify `right` and `left` properties, and set them to `0`, instead of setting width exclusively:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-menu"></div>
    <div class="bottom-menu"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
}
.top-menu, .bottom-menu {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.bottom-menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuf0m41z/8/)

Answer (score 1):

just add the `position:relative;` to your container and don't forgetto add a `width:100%;` to your bottom menu.

here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/wuf0m41z/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try it !!!

```
 .container {
height: 400px;
position: relative;
background-color: green;}

.top-menu {
height: 50px;
background-color: yellow;}

.bottom-menu {
height: 50px;
background-color: yellow;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;}
```

Comment: Önder, could you explain a bit more rather than just supplying code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct now just have to add width.

```
.bottom-menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100%;
}
```